# How can I get the milk cost using func (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, func

I'm studying the Swift code now, and for the func, I have a question.

The code is

```
func getMilk(bottles: Int) {
    var cost = bottles * 1.5
    print("Milk cost is $\(cost)")
}

getMilk(bottles: 4)
```

Comment: You want a return value? `func getMilk(bottles: Int) -> Float { ... return cost }`, and `let cost = getMilk(bottles: 4)`?

Comment: Thank you!!

`func getMilk(bottles: Float) {
    let cost: Float = bottles * 1.5
    print("Milk cost is \(cost)")
}

getMilk(bottles: 2)
`

Comment: [Swift functions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

```
    func getMilk(numberOfBottles: Int,
                 bottleVolume: Float) -> Float {
        var cost = Float(numberOfBottles) * bottleVolume
        return cost
    }
    print("Milk func return: \(getMilk(bottles: 5, bottleVolume: 1.5))")
```

This example will return the total volume of milt in bottles, given the number of bottles and each bottle's volume.

Great job on deciding to learn Swift!

Please remember not to use magic numbers in your code.